# Website layout all messed up on Android only

Tags: android, html, css, web, mobile-website

My personnal website is all messed up when i display it on Android devices.

I've tested my site on all major browsers on Windows and Mac OS X:
- IE7 to IE10
- Chrome
- FireFox
- Opera
- Safari

And they all display my website correctly.
I've also tested on some Apple devices and they also display correctly.

But I've tried on a Nexus 4 and a Nexus 7 and the layout is all messed up.
The page is all zoomed out and the menu seems to be outside the viewport.

I'm lost here and any help would be appreciated.

http://www.narcissusphoto.com/

Comment: Dude, if you took those photos, they're pretty good man. What do you shoot with? Also, please post code, or at least a jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi, I did take the photos. I shoot with a Nikon D600 and 2 primes. 85mm and 50mm 1.8g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add media queries in your css to look your website for mobile devices. Please refer the below link and accordingly you need to make changes in css.

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps

Comment: This seems to be the best way to make it work. I've added the meta viewport tag and pretty close to being perfect. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the fixed background on the body element.